# How to do BULK INSERT in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, csv, syntax, insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to do a bulk insert into tables from a CSV file using Oracle11. My problem is that the database is on a remote machine which I can sqlpl to using this:

```
sqlpl username@oracle.machineName
```

Unfortunately the `sqlldr` has trouble connecting using the following command:

```
sqlldr userid=userName/PW@machinename control=BULK_LOAD_CSV_DATA.ctl log=sqlldr.log
```

Error is:

```
Message 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ULMessage 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UL
```

Now having given up on this approach I tried writing a basic sql script, but I am unsure of the proper Oracle keyword for `BULK`. I know this works in MySql but I get:

```
unknown command beginning "BULK INSER..."
```

When running the script:

```
BULK INSERT <TABLE_NAME>
FROM 'CSVFILE.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

I don't care which one works! Either one will do, I just need a little help.

Comment: First, I assume you mean "sqlplus" rater than "sqlpl".  Are you running `SQL*Loader` on the same machine that you are running `SQL*Plus` on?  Why are you using "oracle.machinename" as the TNS alias for one and "machinename" as the TNS alias for the the other?  Oracle does not have a `BULK INSERT` statement.  You would use `SQL*Loader` if the CSV file exists on the client or external tables if the CSV file exists on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am a dumb dumb! I forgot to add oracle/bin to my path!

If you have found this post, add the bin directory to your path (linux) using the following commands:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/client
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time ....